# What does the content of the short[] array of AudioRecord.read() represent in Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I use AudioRecord to record the incoming sounds. This is my loop:

```
while (isRecording)
{
  readBytes = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
  Log.w("DEBUG", "Readbytes: "+readBytes);
  for(short b:buffer)
  {          
    Log.w("DEBUG", "Data: "+b);
  }
}
```

I have to check if the sound has specific characteristics so I examine the *buffer* array. It contains number from -32,768 to 32,768.

What do these numbers represent? Volume? Amplitude? What means if they are under 0?

Comment: Check [this Wikipedia article about PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5891128/752320).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Your comment should become an answer.

Comment: To tell the truth, I voted to close as a duplicate. I'd feel kinda bad answering it now.

Comment: Having an answer is what matters to me now :) I wasn't thorough enough when looked for an answer.