# Get audio sample value

Tags: c#

How can print and modify audio sample value in C#?

```
byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\audioclip.wav");

for (int i = 44; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" byte " + i + "  value  " + array[i]);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Is it right?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? why does your loop start at 44?

Comment: I try to perform Audio Steganography (hide text in audio sample),and my loop start at 44 because the (wav) audio file actual data (sample) start in it (44).

Comment: You dont need minus 1 in your for condition. `i < array.Length`- is the end of the file. (since you do lower than). - I don't understand what exactly is the issue?

Comment: O.k, Is there is another code to get audio sample value?

Comment: Have you tried wavestream?

Comment: No. I don't  use it  before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.wav` files **may** be compressed, if so the sample values won't be stored as simple bytes.  You would need to use a library (as mentioned in the comments).

If your file is uncompressed then you are almost correct.  Uncompressed `.wav` files contain 16bit samples, not 8bit.  So `ReadAllBytes` isn't very helpful.

Instead use a `BinaryReader` and `reader.ReadInt16()` to read each sample, eg.

```
List<Int16> sampleBuffer = new List<Int16>();
using(var inputStream = File.Open(inputFile)){
 using (var reader = new BinaryReader(inputStream))      
 {           
     while (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)
         sampleBuffer.Add(reader.ReadInt16());      
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why when I print the result of list (sampleBuffer) value there is a negative number in the beginning of results.

Comment: @Yas I believe that is correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890499/pcm-audio-amplitude-values